# Expected 2D Array,got 1D array instead.Where's the mistake?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, pca

**I am beginning to learn SVM and PCA.I tried to apply SVM on the Sci-Kit Learn 'load_digits' dataset.**

**When i apply the .fit method to SVC,i get an error:**

"Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 1.9142151   0.58897807  1.30203491 ...  1.02259477  1.07605691
-1.25769703].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature

or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."

Here is the code i wrote:**

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
X_digits, y_digits = load_digits(return_X_y=True)
data = scale(X_digits)
pca=PCA(n_components=10).fit_transform(data)
reduced_data = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(data)
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC(kernel='rbf', C=1E6)
X=[reduced_data[:,0]
y=reduced_data[:,1]
clf.fit(X, y)
```

**Can someone help me out?Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error results from the fact that `clf.fit()` requires the array `X` to be of dimension 2 (currently it is 1 dimensional), and by using `X.reshape(-1, 1)`, `X` becomes a `(N,1)` (2D - as we would like) array, as opposed to `(N,)` (1D), where N is the number of samples in the dataset. However, I also believe that your interpretation of `reduced_data` may be incorrect (from my limited experience of `sklearn`):

- The `reduced_data` array that you have contains **two principle components** (the two most important features in the dataset, `n_components=2`), which you should be using as the new "data" (`X`).
- Instead, you have taken the first column of `reduced_data` to be the samples `X`, and the second column to be the target values `y`. It is to my understanding that a better approach would be to make `X = reduced_data` since the sample data should consist of both PCA features, and make `y = y_digits`, since the labels (targets) are unchanged by PCA.

(I also noticed you defined `pca = PCA(n_components=10).fit_transform(data)`, but did not go on to use it, so I have removed it from the code in my answer).

As a result, you would have something like this:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X_digits, y_digits = load_digits(return_X_y=True)
data = scale(X_digits)
# pca=PCA(n_components=10).fit_transform(data)
reduced_data = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(data)

clf = SVC(kernel='rbf', C=1e6)
clf.fit(reduced_data, y_digits)
```

I hope this has helped!

Comment: **thank you so much!I was stuck with this for hours.**